# PHP Sessions support

Tags: php, session, forms

I have never worked with sessions before so just need a bit of guidance. Some data from a form needs to be held whilst someone logs in. So I have got this far.

```
<?php
$_SESSION['tmp']['booking-form'] = array(
    'GT_title' => $SEStitle,
    'GT_actual_duration' => $SESactualduration,
    'SEScalstartdate' => $calstartdate,
    'GT_picture' => $picture,
    'GT_total_duration' => $SEStotalduration,
    'GT_total_dives' => $SEStotaldives,
    'GT_total_price' => $SEStotalprice,
    'GT_total_duration' => $SEStotalduration,
    'GT_specifications' => $SESspecifications
);
?>
```

Three questions.

1. Where do I put this code as all the named fields in the array exist in a form towards the bottom of the page before the log in process begins.
2. Is that all the code I need or do I need to put something else somewhere else.
3. What do I do to call this session when the client has finished logging in and has been redirected to the booking area where I want this data to be called back up.

Answer (score 2):

Check http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp and http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php . Hope this will help you.

Edit:

Your code should something like :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['temp'] = array('GT_title' => $SEStitle, 'GT_actual_duration' => $SESactualduration, 'SEScalstartdate' => $calstartdate, 'GT_picture' => $picture, 'GT_total_duration' => $SEStotalduration, 'GT_total_dives' => $SEStotaldives, 'GT_total_price' => $SEStotalprice, 'GT_total_duration' => $SEStotalduration, 'GT_specifications' => $SESspecifications);


echo $_SESSION['temp']['GT_title'];//the value of $SEStitle will be here...
```

It might give you an idea what is going on behind the scene. Also ***REMEMBER*** that you have to call `session_start()` function in the top of the page where you want to use `$_SESSION[]`

Comment: @armonge i didn't find any useful information about SESSION at w3fools.com .

Comment: I was talking about suggesting w3schools to someone

Comment: @armong: Wow, someone really found sufficient time, money and indignation to put up an anti-w3cschools site?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It's been up for some time actually, and I'd say its PHP tutorials are error free (not 100% sure), so stop posting `w3fools` on it please. They are doing a fine job. +1 :P

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you want to use the session data, call `session_start()` at the top of any page before any output.

You set the `$_SESSION[]` wherever you have the data.

You can get the data after login using the same `$_SESSION[]` array. It will be populated as soon as `session_start()` has been called.

Comment: Right so on the page where I collected data from a form I collected it in an array with <?php $_SESSION['tmp'] = array('GT_title' => $SEStitle, 'GT_actual_duration' => .... etc.  Then on the page I want to call it back up I put <?php session_start() ?> at the very top and the call the date with <?php $_SESSION['tmp']?> Then how do I get the fields out of the session. Do I then put <?php echo $_POST["GT_title"];?> where I want the title etc... ???